# Sending put request working as string but not after json stringify

Tags: angular, ionic2, put, http-put

I am sending a PUT request using REST API, the base mandatory field to be sent is Id.

So I am compiling this as an User Object in typescript and sending it using http.put using angular 2 in ionic 2 app.

```
let bodyString = JSON.stringify(userDetails); 
   this.http.put(userurl, bodyString, {headers:headers})
```

I am getting this error 
[image]

If you could see I am packing id in it. But if I do the same like,

```
var bodyString = "Id=33053793&FirstName=test&=";
```

instead of accessing JSON object and stringifying it, it works, not sure what is happening and why this is not working.

I prefer using JSON object as there are more nested parameters to be passed than just one to 2 to be handled as string concat.

Comment: Do the types of Id match? Maybe the server awaits an Id as String?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with angular. The issue you are getting is related to the way the server is configured to handle requests.